# Can't change texture of material - SparkAR v89?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

Working in script here in SparkAR v89, and in previous versions, to programmatically change the texture of a material, this would work:

```
const Materials = require('Materials');
const Textures = require('Textures');

Promise.all([

    Scene.root.findFirst('plane4'),

]).then(function (results) {

    const plane4 = results[0];

    const ipadPerfect = Scene.root.findFirst('ipad-perfect');
    const iphonePerfect = Scene.root.findFirst('iphone-perfect');
    const computerPerfect = Scene.root.findFirst('computer-perfect');

    // Get the timer ready
    start();

    function start() {

      const bgMat = Materials.findFirst('bg');
      const mutableScreen = Materials.findFirst('mutablescreen');

      var texture = Textures.findFirst('unnamed-min');

      bgMat.diffuse = texture;
      bgMat.emission = texture;
      mutableScreen.diffuse = texture;
      mutableScreen.emission = texture;
```

Even changing out findFirst with `get` or `findAll` , this yields nothing. How can I change the texture of a material now?

Answer (score 1):

Requesting textures, materials, and scene objects is an operation that takes some time. Starting with version v85, for such things, you need to use methods like `findFirst` in the `Promise.All` block. Just transfer the request for textures and materials to the same block where you request `plane4`. Your other code seems to be correct.

```
const Materials = require('Materials');
const Textures = require('Textures');
const Scene = require('Scene');

Promise.all([

    Scene.root.findFirst('plane4'),
    Scene.root.findFirst('ipad-perfect'),
    Scene.root.findFirst('iphone-perfect'),
    Scene.root.findFirst('computer-perfect'),
    Materials.findFirst('bg'),
    Materials.findFirst('mutablescreen'),
    Textures.findFirst('unnamed-min')


]).then(function (results) {

    const plane4 = results[0];

    const ipadPerfect = results[1];
    const iphonePerfect = results[2];
    const computerPerfect = results[3];
    const bgMat = results[4];
    const mutableScreen = results[5];
    const texture = results [6];

    // Get the timer ready
    start();

    function start() {


      bgMat.diffuse = texture;
      bgMat.emission = texture;
      mutableScreen.diffuse = texture;
      mutableScreen.emission = texture;
```

Comment: thank you for this, however it doesnt work. Can you see my new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887649/sparkar-cant-change-texture-of-material-in-code