# SparkAR - can't change texture of material in code?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I've here made sure to find all objects, Materials and Textures in the `Promise.all` of my script given that they take time to load in. I then set my textures to my materials, and no errors are drawn. However, the materials do not change.

I can't find anything wrong with my code:

```
Promise.all([

  //These take time to acquire..
    Scene.root.findFirst('ipad-perfect'),
    Scene.root.findFirst('iphone-perfect'),
    Scene.root.findFirst('computer-perfect'),
    Materials.findFirst('bg'),
    Materials.findFirst('mutablescreen'),
    Textures.findFirst('SUPERHOT-min')

]).then(function (results) {

    const ipadPerfect = results[0];
    const iphonePerfect = results[1];
    const computerPerfect = results[2];
    const bgMat = results[3];
    const mutableScreen = results[4];
    const superHotTexture = results[5];

    var devicesRot = 0;
    var gamesRot = 0;

    // Get the timer ready
    start();

    function start() {

      var texture = superHotTexture;
      bgMat.diffuse = texture;
      bgMat.emission = texture;
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I programmatically change the texture of a Material?

Answer (score 0):

if there is no error showing do check the names u have mentioned its case sensitive so that might be some reason . put a catch statement and they seeing what's happening to the "then " part